# trying to output result of function

Tags: c#, oop, console

I'm making mini calculator.

My code:

```
public class Calc
{
    public double a = 1;
    public double b = 1;
    public double plus()
    {
        return a+b;
    }
    public double minus()
    {
        return a-b;
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    Calc sq = new Calc();
    Console.WriteLine("\na+b:");
    Console.WriteLine(sq.plus());
    Console.WriteLine("\na-b:");
    Console.WriteLine(sq.minus());
}
```

My problems:

1. I want to show result from function without Console.WriteLine, what I should change in my code?
2. Is this code OOP? I want to improve my code, but I don't know how to do. Should I use variables like this?

   `Console.WriteLine(sq.plus(a, b));`

Comment: How and where do you want to show the result from the function? If you don't want to use `Console.WriteLine` you don't want to show it on the console. But where else? And yes, the code is OOP, although not very useful.

Comment: Hello, Tim, I saw many codes where the result is showing without Console.WriteLine (just like this: sq.plus();)

Comment: For that you'll have to put the `Console.WriteLine` in your `plus` method. Without it, you can not display your results in console.

Comment: @Shaharyar but how to remove "return" then? If I use "WriteLine" in my method, I need to remove "return".

Comment: Either keep both WriteLine and return, or remove return and change the return type of the method to `void` like this: `public void plus()`

Comment: like this,  public void minus()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a-b);
    }

Comment: If you do not want to return, remove  return, other wise you can keep both.

Comment: Thank you, I just added WriteLine and changed return line to "return 1;". And my last question, what should be the best way to use variables? What is the better way when I have more than 2 methods (plus, minus, power and so on): use sq.plus(5,5) or use sq.plus() and get variables directly from Calc class?

Comment: @JohnDeepy If you don't want to return a value, you should change the method declaration to be `public void plus()` rather than `public double plus()`. No point in having a return type with an arbitrary, hard-coded value like `return 1;` if you don't ever actually need it. It's not indicative of what the function does, or did. Also, you might want to look into getting input from the user (`Console.ReadLine()`) and setting `a` and `b` in your `Calc` class with the user-supplied values, rather than using the hardcoded `a = 1;` and `b = 1;` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing functional code, so OOP is not a good fit here. Your `plus` and `minus` methods are deterministic, so turn them into static, thread safe functions.

You should not put the `WriteLine` calls into the `Calc` class as you are then mixing concerns, rather than separating them, as the class then becomes responsible for both calculating and displaying the results of the calculation. This makes testing harder and thus your code becomes less maintainable. So I'd rewrite it as:

```
public static class Calc
{
    public static double Plus(double a, double b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }

    public static double Minus(double a, double b)
    {
        return a-b;
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\na+b:");
    Console.WriteLine(Calc.Plus(1,1));
    Console.WriteLine("\na-b:");
    Console.WriteLine(Calc.Minus(1,1));
}
```